' 'mgs.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. ' Even with correct system variables
I'm currently using the newest Version of MiKTeX (24.1 I think) on Windows 10.
Whenever I try to compile anything using DVI-PS-PDF Chain (Both using LuaLatex and Latex), I get the following error:

Process started: ps2pdf.exe -shell-escape "file".ps
'mgs.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

From what I understand this is caused by mgs.exe not being in the expected directory when ps2pdf is executed. I have tried fixing this error by manually adding the correct path (C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64) to the environment variable 'Path'.
However, this doesn't fix the issue and normally I just got frustrated looking for other possible fixes and just switch to TeXLive (which works, but I really prefer MiKTeX).
I'm hoping that anyone smarter than me has managed to fix this issue or has any idea on what else I could try. If so, please share :)

ps2pdf works fine in my miktex. Which means you have local problem and need to investigate how the pathes are set when you call the command.

How do I do that?

I don't have a source for this information, but I think that MiKTeX not only uses an outdated ghostscript, but also has path naming conflicts with ghostscript. I had a similar problem one time, and switching to TeXLive fixed it completely. I tried fixing MiKTeX too, and succeeded by consulting a computer expert who renamed my paths for me. It broke again when I updated MiKTeX, hence my permanent move to TeXLive.

Actually I found the issue. It was me. I changed the local variables instead of the system variables.
Basically I was too dumb to follow these instructions.
